# web browser extension: halt all *further* javascript execution

Tags: javascript, web-browser

After a web page is loaded, it often keeps eating anywhere from 25% to 100% of my CPU. Sometimes, it's to render some excessive or poorly designed graphics somewhere, like an animated background. Other times, it is much more evil—unsolicited use of my CPU in somebody's supercomputer, for instance. I'd like a button that when pushed halts all further javascript execution in a given tab until the button is pushed again, or until a different web site is navigated to.

Please note, this is not the same as the already-existing "stop" button. That button does *not* stop further javascript execution.

How this is implemented, or what browser I would have to use (so long as it's not ie or safari) is unimportant to me.

Comment: So what is needed is a browser extension that halts javascript execution after a certain time, maybe so it has time to load, but stop the begmail and tripe discounts a few seconds after loading, does this sound like it?

Comment: What platform ate we talking about

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox (On windows at least) there is an addon called **Noscript**.

It shows you all the scripts on the site and you can decide which ones to block. These decisions are saved per site.

For a new site, I start with all blocked. Then I  enable the innocuous looking ones, one at a time  until the site works.